# How to create nested __init__ functions in a inheritance chain?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm trying to implement inheritance system where child class will add a value to dictionary that he received from ansister.

For instance:

```
class First:
    specificator = {'first':1}
    inherited_specificator = {}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ???

class Second(First):
    specificator = {'second':2}

class Third(Second):
    specificator = {'third':3}
```

So i wish I can implement init method that Third class instance will have inherited_specificator = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3}

What I've tried:

Create init method that will be calling parent init method that will be calling... and so on to collect specificators from all top level classes.

```
class First:
    specificator = {'first':1}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        if not getattr(self, 'inherited_specificator ', None): setattr(self, 'inherited_specificator', {})
        self.inherited_specificator = {**self.inherited_specificator , **self.specificator}
```

However it didn't work for me for some reason, Third().inherited_specificator was equal to {'third':3}. Maybe I don't completely understand the super() method workstyle, but I wasn't able to find detailed info about my case.

Also I tried to create set_specificator function that will be called from init and where it should add current class specificator to inherited one, but the same problem appeared and all I got is {'third':3}.

If there's solution for my case? Thanks in advance.

Update:
I'm looking for solution without overwriting init method if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the method resolution order (MRO), checking each class for a `specificator` attribute that can be used to update `inherited_specificator`. You'll probably want iterate in reverse order, so that child classes can override inherited values.

```
class First:
    specificator = {'first':1}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inherited_specificator = {}
        for s in reversed(type(self).mro()):
            try:
                self.inherited_specificator.update(s.specificator)
            except AttributeError:
                pass


class Second(First):
    specificator = {'second':2}


class Third(Second):
    specificator = {'third':3}


t = Third()
print(t.inherited_specificator)
```

This manual walking of the MRO is necessary because only one `__init__` will be called per instance. That call will only see the `specificator` attribute of the actual instance passed to that call: there is no "intermediate" instances of `First` and `Second` on which `First.__init__` will be called before your actual instance of `Third` is passed to `First.__init__`.

Alternatively, you can make `inherited_specificator` a class attribute (which makes more sense, IMO) instead of an instance attribute, and define it using `__init_subclass__` (which gets called when the class is defined, not when it is instantiated).

```
class Specification:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

        cls.inherited_specificator = \
           getattr(cls, 'inherited_specificator', {})\ 
           | getattr(cls, 'specificator', {})


class First(Specification):
    specificator = {'first':1}


class Second(First):
    specificator = {'second':2}


class Third(Second):
    specificator = {'third':3}
```

The key here is that we (try to) access the inherited value of `inherited_specificator` before creating the new class's own value, which will be the combination of the inherited value and the value of the class's `specificator` attribute, if defined.

I'm using the new dict merge operator introduced in Python 3.9. In earlier versions, use something like

```
def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    inherited = getattr(cls, 'inherited_specificator', {})
    d = cls.inherited_specificator = {}
    new_values = getattr(cls, 'specificator', {})
    d.update(**inherited, **new_values)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: (Ignore my previous comment if you saw it before I deleted it.)

Comment: yes and googled the __init_subclass__, so i was actually waiting because it seemed like perspective way. I tried implement something like this but i was't able even to find this methods because googling 'python initialize class' always gives you novice tutorials. So there is no way using the subclass method>

Comment: OK, I think I have something I like. My first attempt was causing each subclass to update the same inherited value of `inherited_specificator`, rather than creating a class-local version *using* the inherited value.

Comment: Man, thank you a lot, worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you want:

```
class First:
  def __init__(self):
    self.specificator = {'first':1}

class Second(First):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.specificator['second'] = 2

class Third(Second):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.specificator['third'] = 3
```

Then there is the output:

```
> f = First()
> s = Second()
> t = Third()
 
> f.specificator
{'first': 1}
> s.specificator
{'first': 1, 'second': 2}
> t.specificator
{'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Note that this doesn't have to be done in this order; I simply did it for demonstration. You could still do:

```
> t = Third()
> t.specificator
{'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if there possibility to do the same but with same init method?

Answer (score 0):

Including the inheritance of the parameters, and isolation in an `inherited_specificator`:

```
from copy import copy

class First:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(" > called First.__init__()")
        self.specificator = {"first": 1}
        print("specificator: %s" % self.specificator)
        print(" < end First.__init__()")

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(" > called Second.__init__()")
        super().__init__(self)
        self.inherited_specificator = copy(self.specificator)
        self.specificator["second"] = 2
        print("inherited_specificator: %s" % self.inherited_specificator)
        print("specificator: %s" % self.specificator)
        print(" < end Second.__init__()")

class Third(Second):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(" > called Third.__init__()")
        super().__init__(self)
        self.inherited_specificator.update(self.specificator)
        self.specificator = {"third": 3}
        print("inherited_specificator: %s" % self.inherited_specificator)
        print("specificator: %s" % self.specificator)
        print(" < end Third.__init__()")

obj = Third()
```

gives the output:

```
 > called Third.__init__()
 > called Second.__init__()
 > called First.__init__()
specificator: {'first': 1}
 < end First.__init__()
inherited_specificator: {'first': 1}
specificator: {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
 < end Second.__init__()
inherited_specificator: {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
specificator: {'third': 3}
 < end Third.__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if there possibility to do the same but with same init method?

Comment: assuming you want the `specificator` to be inherited from parent->[grand]children, AFAIK they need to be defined in each class' `__init__()`. Or do you mean fetching the grandparent's `specificator` from `Third.__init__()` ?

Comment: Yes, I thought it can be implemented like collecting grandparents specificators in a child init method

Comment: Played with `super()` a bit, but it can only invoke parent methods. I tried using a method, but the method will action on the current object/class, not the parent class.

Comment: Yes, same, luckily chepner found a mro ladder way